# CakePhp 3.8 with Jquery autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery-ui, cakephp, design-patterns, jquery-ui-autocomplete, cakephp-3.8

I'm trying to use the autocomplete jquery function to complete a field with one of two source values: ['pere', 'mele']. unfortunately it does not work.

**default.ctp**

```
     <script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <?php echo $this->Html->script(['single']) ?>
```

**in view file**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create($societa); ?>       

<fieldset>
     <h1>Aggiungi Società</h1>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <?php echo $this->Form->control('nome_societa',['class'=>'form-control','required' => true]);?>  
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
         <?php echo $this->Form->control('nome_societa_abbreviato',['class'=>'form-control','required' => true]);?>  
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
         <?php echo $this->Form->control('sede',['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'naruto','required' => true]);?>  
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
         <?php echo $this->Form->control('cap',['class'=>'form-control','required' => true]);?>  
        </div>  
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
         <?php echo $this->Form->control('citta',['class'=>'form-control']);?>  
        </div>  
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
         <?php echo $this->Form->control('pr',['class'=>'form-control']);?>  
        </div>  
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
         <?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Salva'),['class'=>'btn btn-primary']);?>  
        </div>  
    </div>           
</fieldset> 
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>  
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Indietro', ['action'=>'index'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

**in js file single.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#naruto").autocomplete({
        source:['pere','mele']
    });    
});
```

**in console google chrome**

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://bootstrapcdn.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
add#:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://forum.jquery.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
add#:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://forum.jquery.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
add#:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://jquery.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

unfortunately the file does not work even if the console does not give errors

Comment: try alert(); inside your document ready function of  single js file .

Comment: `$('document').ready(function(){
    alert(console.log($("#naruto").autocomplete({
        source:['pere','mele']
       
    })));    
});`


`localhost: undefined`

I don't understand why it returns undefined

Comment: @MdShifatulIslam what do you think about it ?

Answer (score 0):

OK so it works. Fixed the various Jquery UI calls. Resolved

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Responsive sidebar template with sliding effect and dropdown menu based on bootstrap 3">
<title>Calciotel</title>

<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.3.1/litera/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->css(['jquery-ui.theme.min','jquery-ui.min','prova']);

echo $this->Html->script(['bootstrap.min','jquery-3.4.1.min','jquery-ui.min','prova','single','popper.min.js']);

echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
echo $this->fetch('meta');
echo $this->fetch('css');
echo $this->fetch('script');
echo $this->Html->charset();

?>
```